# Show Python method's API documentation from a URL on hover in VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, code-documentation

**Is it possible to have VSCode show a Python method's online documentation upon mouse-over/hover?**

For example, [PyTorch API Docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/index.html) are hosted online and the method hierarchy is simple to navigate. When I hover of a method from the PyTorch library, I'd like to see the API documentation from that URL, **not** just the various method signatures.

This feature is available to Java Developer using Eclipse: The user can configure Eclipse to pull API documentation from a URL (e.g., the [List API JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html)) on a project-by-project basis. Here's an example of the popup that shows up in Eclipse for the `List.of()` method:

---

[image]

---

Notice that along with the method signature is a short description of the method ("returns an unmodifiable list...") along with additional helpful information (e.g., Type parameters, Parameters, and Returns)

To clarify: I'm not only looking for a popup showing the method signature(s), but also the associated documentation. For example: VSCode only displays the method signatures for `torch.rand()`, but the PyTorch API documentation includes the [full description](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.rand.html).

Comment: Usually, this is provided by python language server. It may be pylance or jedi. It sounds like a new function request. It would be a better way to request this function to developers in [github](https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @MingJie-MSFT : I submitted a feature request [here](https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/3852) but I'm keeping the question open here in the off chance that someone has a current working solution.